# SharePoint Modern Search get user organization

Tags: search, sharepoint-online

I´m building a people directory in SPO with Modern Search v4 and I want to display the organization/company which the user belongs to. Therefor I use LocalPeopleResults as the Result Source.

I´ve added OrgNames as well as an created RefinableString with the "People:ORGANIZATIONNAMES" crawled Propertie to the "Selected properties" but the search did not show the user company.

So what propertie is required to show the company value?